# How to dynamically add all methods of a class into another class

Tags: jenkins, reflection, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a [global shared library on Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#global-shared-libraries) implicitly loaded on all pipelines, then my `Jenkinsfile` is like that:

```
new com.company.Pipeline()()
```

And then the shared library has on directory `src/com/company` some files, below the `Pipeline.groovy` class:

```
package com.company  

import static Utils.*

def call() {
  // some stuff here...
}
```

The problem is, this way I have to static declare all methods, thus I lose the context and cannot access jenkins' methods easly without the `Pipeline` class' instance. As you can see [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#accessing-steps) they passing `this` to the method `mvn`.

Thinking of avoid this I was wondering about dynamically add all methods as closures by calling `Utils.install this` instead of using `import static Utils.*`, then my `Utils.groovy` is something like that:

```
package com.company

private Utils() {}

static def install(def instance) {
  def utils = new Utils()
  // Some extra check needed here I know, but it is not the problem now
  for (def method in (utils.metaClass.methods*.name as Set) - (instance.metaClass.methods*.name as Set)) {
    def closure = utils.&"$method"
    closure.delegate = instance
    instance.metaClass."$method" = closure
  }
}

def someMethod() {
  // here I want to use sh(), tool(), and other stuff freely.
}
```

But it raises an `GStringImpl` cannot be cast to `String` error, I believe `.&` do not work with variables, how can I convert a method into closure having the method name on a variable? I have the [`MetaMethod`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/MetaMethod.html) mostly being a [`CachedMethod`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/reflection/CachedMethod.html) instance, if it were possible to turn it a [`ClosureMetaMethod`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/metaclass/ClosureMetaMethod.html) instance maybe the problem can be solved, but whenever I search for method to closure conversion for groovy I just found the `.&` solution!

If I use `instance.metaClass.someMethod = utils.&someMethod` it do work, but I want it to be dinamic as I add new methods without needing to worry about sharing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to do it dynamically. Notation `utils.&someMethod` returns a [`MethodClosure`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/MethodClosure.html) object that can be simply instantiated with its constructor:

```
MethodClosure(Object owner, String method)
```

Consider following example:

```
class Utils {
    def foo() {
        println "Hello, Foo!"
    }
    def bar() {
        println "Hello, Bar!"
    }
}

class Consumer {
}

def instance = new Consumer()
def utils = new Utils()

(utils.metaClass.methods*.name - instance.metaClass.methods*.name).each { method ->
    def closure = new MethodClosure(utils, method)
    closure.delegate = instance
    instance.metaClass."$method" = closure
}

instance.foo() // Prints "Hello, Foo!"
instance.bar() // Prints "Hello, Bar!"
```

In this example I use `def closure = new MethodClosure(utils, method)` to get object method reference and then add this method to `instance` object. I hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect, it worked, just for register I didn't use each because Jenkins complains it is not serializable, but that solved the problem, thanks.

Comment: @TiagoPimenta Cool, I'm glad I could help you :)