# How to declare a constructor or extends a class of a groovy script?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy

I am working on a [shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) for Jenkins, and I want to access some utilities methods between some classes, but not all of them, thus I have established some statements:

- I would like to avoid using static methods, since it does not access pipeline steps directly, and passing the pipeline instance every call would be a pain;
- I would like to avoid a singleton as well, or prefixing every method call with the util class' instance;
- Since it is not supposed to be shared between all classes I would like to avoid putting every method as a file on `vars/` special directory, but I would like a similar behavior;
- Despite extending the class would be a anti-pattern, it would be acceptable, though I would like to avoid the verbose Java syntax for declaring the class the same name as the file, once it is implicit in groovy;

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600613/how-to-dynamically-add-all-methods-of-a-class-into-another-class) does solve my problem partially, although there are issues with serialization, I noted that when I use checkpoint and some build is resumed from some stage, the instance loses all extra methods.

This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831615/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-constructor-for-a-groovy-script) would have helped me fix the serialization issue, however the author seems the have solved the root cause of his problem using a way that is not the original question titled for.

Is there a way to extends a implicit script class in groovy without using the `class NameOfFile extends SomeOtherClass { put every thing inside this block }` syntax? And without working with inner-class?

Or else, is there a way to declare a constructor using the script groovy syntax analogue as the previous question?

Or even, is there a way to change the serialization behavior to install the extra methods again after unserializing?

### Appendix

The script syntax works more-or-less like this:

Consider the content of file `src/cicd/pipeline/SomePipeline.groovy`:

```
package cicd.pipeline

// there is no need to wrap everything inside class SomePipeline,
// since it is implicit

def method() {
  // instance method, here I can access pipeline steps freely
}

def static otherMethod() {
  // static method, here it is unable to access pipeline steps
  // without a instance
}

@groovy.transform.Field
def field

def call() {
  // if the class is used as method it will run
  this.method()
  SomePipeline.otherMethod() // or simply otherMethod() should work
  this.field = 'foo'
  println "this instance ${this.getClass().canonicalName} should be cicd.pipeline.SomePipeline"
}

// any code other than methods or variables with @Field
// annotation will be inside a implicit run method that is
// triggered likewise main method but isn't a static one
def localVar = 'foo'
println "It will not execute on constructor since it is on run: $localVar"
println "Method: ${org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils.sanitize(new Throwable()).stackTrace[0].methodName}"
println "this instance ${this.getClass().canonicalName} should be cicd.pipeline.SomePipeline"
```

If I was going to use the Java verbose syntax I would have to wrap almost everything inside a `class SomePipeline` which is implicit in groovy, this is the script syntax I want to keep.

Comment: Could you share the expected syntax?

Comment: @daggett It's hard to say what it will gonna be since that is what I'm asking for, the questions I linked express the feelings I expect, but I'll try to describe it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that `this.getClass().superclass.canonicalName` when outside Jenkins pipeline is `groovy.lang.Script` and when inside pipeline is `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript` and based on [this resource](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/BaseScript.html) I was able to elaborate the following solution:

```
abstract class CustomScript extends org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript {
  public CustomScript() {
    // do something here, it will always execute regardless
    // serialization, and before everything
  }
}

@groovy.transform.BaseScript CustomScript baseScript
```

That is it, worked as expected! Of course you can elaborate this solution better in order to reduce repeating and avoid inner-classes, but I will leave it for your imagination.